# syntax error, unexpected keyword_when, expecting $end in ruby code, codecademy, a night at the movies 6/10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am practicing ruby at codecademy.com, I am getting a strange error, but when I see the code it looks correct to me. 
Following is my code, (you can also see the code and its output live at [**CodePad**](http://codepad.org/FAcz8CSy)

```
movies = {
    'Janwar' =>  4,
    'Tum Bin' =>  3,
    'PK' => 3
}

puts "Select your favorite movie"
puts "type \"add\" to add a movie to the list"
puts "type \"delete\" to delete a movie"
puts "type \"display\" to list the movies"

choice = gets.chomp

case choice
when "add"
    puts "Please say the movie title"
    title = gets.chomp
    puts "What is the rating of the movie"
    rating = gets.
    if  movies[title.to_sym].nil? == true
        movies[title.to_sym] = rating.to_i
    else
        puts "the thing you wanna add is already there"
    end
when "update"
    puts "Updated!"
when "display"
    puts "Movies!"
when "delete"
    puts "Deleted!"
else
    puts "Error!df"
end
```

And this is the error message I get,

```
Line 25: syntax error, unexpected kWHEN, expecting $end
when "update"
    ^
```

Would someone please run this code at CodePad and see what is the error?

Thank You All in Advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you missed a method:

```
 rating = gets. #<<
```

Which you want probably, `rating = gets.chomp`.

Comment: Oh, how can one miss this much simple thing :) Thank You !

Comment: it happens to everyone, even experienced developers ;)